# How to write Links in Comments

Tags: support

What's the syntax when trying to embed links in comments?
[For instance here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21888/how-can-i-convert-ecat-v-file-to-nifti-nii-file-in-python) I tried and failed.

What I tried:

> [url = "www.internet.com"]words here[/url]
> [url = www.internet.com]words here[/url]

Comment: like this [bioinformatics stackexchange](http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this: [bioinformatics stackexchange](http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com)

[bioinformatics stackexchange](http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com)

You can find the relevant documentation here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting, under "Comment formatting".

Comment: [This maybe works](http://www.google.com), edit: oh. It _must _ have http at beginning.